# Eclipse, moving xtext workspace

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, project, xtext

I have an xtext project that I want to move to another computer.
my text project uses some plug-in. if I want to compile my text project the log errors says it don't find the swt class.
adding the swt jar as a library or as a linked project doesn't work.
However, I have found this difference between the working project and the other.
the working one :

[image]

not working one:

[image]
the two projects have the same plugin dependencies  :

[image]
any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Your original Eclipse is 64 bit, is the second Eclipse also 64 bit?

Comment: no, are you sure my original Eclipse os 64 bit ?

Comment: The `org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64` plugin is 64 bit only so your Eclipse (or your Target Platform if you are using one) is 64 bit. This is the plugin that contain the SWT code. If you are using a Target Platform look at the 'Environment' tab to see if a specific architecture is specified.

Comment: @greg-449 it's ok, you were right. if you want, you can make a response and i will accepte it.